# How to get link to download file in pdf? (Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following structure in the details.html

```
<p>Files:
{% for file in files %}
    <p><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file.name }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

This link returns the correct url.

```
http://localhost/media/file.pdf
```

However, every time I click, instead of downloading the file, it returns error 404.

What is the correct way to do this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this on the local development server or in production?

My guess is you haven't [configured Django to serve /media/ files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development).

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

However, do note the admonition in the documentation:

> This is not suitable for production use!

Answer (score 2):

`<p><a href="{{ file }}" download>{{ file.name }}</a></p>`

if you try to query to on database and print in client side, so in your anchor link write a right path

example:

```
<p><a href="/media/{{ file }}" download>{{ file.name }}</a></p>
```

Comment: The model returns the url, so I do not need to specify the correct path. 
Anyway thank you. I already solve. in development just add to url.py. In deploy I will let nginx capture the urls.